# Azure Cosmos DB (EF/Core) - ID column contains class name

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I have a `.NET Core 3.1` API Project which has a Cosmos DB storage being handled via `Entity Framework` *(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos - v3.1.5)*.

I have a database model:

```
public class BikeRental
{
    [Key] public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string BikeId { get; set; }
    public string ShopId { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a fluent configuration which maps the entity names to camel case:

```
  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var property in entity.GetProperties())
                {
                    var camel = Char.ToLowerInvariant(property.Name[0]) + property.Name.Substring(1);
                    property.SetPropertyName(camel);
                    property.SetColumnName(camel);

                }
            }
}
```

Upon saving to Cosmos, the 'id' now contains the class name of BikeRental:

```
    {
    "id": "BikeRental|0042a855-0473-41d3-a344-49af808a0ffd",
    "bikeId": "eb65b93b-17d3-4829-9729-d48c029211fe2",
    "shopId": "636c08c4-600d-458a-98b7-8d312b8c18d2",

    "_rid": "2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/2QZIAA==/colls/2QZIAMVYbVQ=/docs/2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-4627-f721b0e701d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1592564051
    }
```

If I change my model to have a lowercase id, as opposed to Id the record writes to Cosmos as I'd expect:

```
{
    "id": "ec86b971-b305-4055-b29f-8a4a7c5bf125",
    "bikeId": "eb65b93b-17d3-4829-9729-d48c029211fe2",
    "shopId": "636c08c4-600d-458a-98b7-8d312b8c18d2",

    "_rid": "2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/2QZIAA==/colls/2QZIAMVYbVQ=/docs/2QZIAMVYbVQBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000000-0000-0000-4627-f721b0e701d6\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1592564051
}
```

If there is  any help or suggestions on how to resolve this, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that it's trying to add some sort of automatic discriminator.  Try adding and explicitly configuring a discriminator.  Cosmos, by default, puts many different types in the same container so they should have discriminator properties.

Comment: Thanks David. ' .HasNoDiscriminator();' has done the trick, as this will be the only entity stored in this container.